# Is there a way to pass all type template parameters in an old class template into a new class template?

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming, stdtuple

I've created a simple template class called `tuple_tag` which is identical to `std::tuple` but only acts as a **tag**.

```cpp
// tuple_tag
template <typename...> struct tuple_tag {};

// tuple_tag_element
template <size_t I, typename T>
struct tuple_tag_element;

template <size_t I, typename Head, typename... Tail>
struct tuple_tag_element<I, tuple_tag<Head, Tail...>>
: tuple_tag_element<I - 1, tuple_tag<Tail...>> {};

template <typename Head, typename... Tail>
struct tuple_tag_element<0, tuple_tag<Head, Tail...>>
: std::type_identity<Head> {};

// tuple_tag_element_t
template <size_t I, typename T>
using tuple_tag_element_t = tuple_tag_element<I, T>::type;

// tuple_tag_size
template <typename T>
struct tuple_tag_size;

template <typename T> requires (std::is_reference_v<T> || std::is_const_v<T>)
struct tuple_tag_size<T> : tuple_tag_size<std::remove_cvref_t<T>> {};

template <typename... Ts>
struct tuple_tag_size<tuple_tag<Ts...>>
: std::integral_constant<size_t, sizeof...(Ts)> {};

// tuple_tag_size_v
template <typename T>
inline constexpr size_t tuple_tag_size_v = tuple_tag_size<T>::value;
```

Here:

```cpp
using new_type_1 = to_tuple_type<tuple_tag<int, double>>::type; 
// new_type_1 = std::tuple<int, double>;
using new_type_2 = to_tuple_tag_type<std::tuple<int, double>>::type;
// new_type_2 = tuple_tag<int, double>;
```

Where `to_tuple_type` takes a type template parameter `tuple_tag<...>` which will be converted into type `std::tuple<...>`, and `to_tuple_tag_type` takes a type template parameter `std::tuple<...>` which will be converted into type `tuple_tag<...>`.

What I am trying to achieve here is to pass all type template parameters from `tuple_tag` into `std::tuple` and vice-versa.

This is my prototype for `to_tuple_type` where it fails:

```cpp
template <typename TupleTag>
struct to_tuple_type {
    using type = std::tuple<...>;
};
```

Where `type` alias will be expanded into:

```cpp
using type = std::tuple<tuple_tag_element_t<Index, TupleTag>...>;
...
using type = std::tuple<
    tuple_tag_element_t<0, TupleTag>,
    tuple_tag_element_t<1, TupleTag>,
    ...,
    tuple_tag_element_t<N - 1, TupleTag>
>;
```

Where `N` is equal to `tuple_tag_size_v<TupleTag>`.

What I could only think of is to use `std::index_sequence` but I don't know where do I introduce the pack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 steps.  First, make a pack

```
using indexes=std::make_index_sequence<tuple_tag_size<TupleTag>;
```

then have a helper that expands the pack.  I like this one:

```
template<auto x>
using constant_t=std::integral_constant<decltype(x),x>;
template<auto x>
constexpr constant_t<x> constant={};  
template<std::size_t...Is>
constexpr auto all_indexes( std::index_sequence<Is...> ){
  return [](auto f){
    return f(constant<Is>...);
  };
}
```

now we can

```
template<class T>
struct tag_t{using type=T;};
template<class T>
constexpr tag_t<T> tag={};
using type=typename decltype(all_indexes(indexes{})([](auto...Is){
  return tag<std::tuple<tuple_tag_element_t<Is, TupleTag>...>;
}))::type;
```

if that has no tpyos.

Comment: I like how you "if that has no tpyos." with an intentional typo!

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple solution that applies partial template specialization:

```cpp
// to_tuple_type
template <typename Tup>
struct to_tuple_type;

template <typename... Ts>
struct to_tuple_type<tuple_tag<Ts...>> : std::type_identity<std::tuple<Ts...>> {};

// to_tuple_type_t
template <typename Tup>
using to_tuple_type_t = to_tuple_type<Tup>::type;

// to_tuple_tag_type
template <typename Tup>
struct to_tuple_tag_type;

template <typename... Ts>
struct to_tuple_tag_type<std::tuple<Ts...>> : std::type_identity<tuple_tag<Ts...>> {};

// to_tuple_tag_type_t
template <typename Tup>
using to_tuple_tag_type_t = to_tuple_tag_type<Tup>::type;
```